# Are there any books on ROS?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I just wanted to know if there are any books on ROS? I found this:

[http://www.amazon.com/OPERATING-SYSTEM-LAMBERT-HENSSONOW-SURHONE/dp/6133541857](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/6133541857)

but it has no cover or description. Does anyone know anything about this book, or any other books?

Thank you, I appreciate the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9797/are-there-any-books-on-ros?/) by [amirrustam](https://answers.ros.org/users/454/amirrustam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have more options now (ordered by my preference):

1. [Programming Robots with ROS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01882NRUQ) - Published in 2015. Authors from OSRF and Willow Garage.
2. [Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B0198DXFEW) - Again published in 2015 and has good and updated instruction.
3. [ROS by Example](http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/pirobot) - There are **two new versions** of this book for Hydro released in January and October 2014. The book is practical and great for beginners as well as those who have some experience!
4. [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/) - This book covers most of the basics and does it really well. Short and sweet. The online version is free and the print is available on Amazon fairly cheap too. A good reference for beginners.
5. [Learning ROS for Robotics Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782161449) - This book covers the basics too and is more detailed than "A Gentle Introduction to ROS" mentioned above. But this book is based on fuerte and the old rosbuild system.

I would go for #1 or #2 if I were buying a book right now.

Also, there's now a ROS wiki page for books so expect that to be updated - http://wiki.ros.org/Books

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, there are no ROS books yet. I was wondering about your link, and googled for "betascript publishing". From what I gather, they are a rather dubious publishing company - they seem to rip parts of wikipedia and other copyleft sources, and print them in book form. Which is perfectly legal, but I guess what you get is a print version of the ROS wiki or something like that. If I were you, I'd save the $54.44! :-)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have discussed making a book on ROS which would be auto generated from the wiki. However it only was partially finished.

You can check out the code for creating such a manual at: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_experimental/trunk/rosmanual

Then run to create the pdf:

```
./rosmanual.py ros.toc.txt
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Patrick Goebel just released the first ROS book "ROS By Example - Volume 1".
You can buy it here: http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-volume-1/ebook/product-20349511.html

---

Originally posted by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) with karma: 901 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This book is very helpful for beginners  [www.cse.sc.edu/~jokane/agitr/](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/)

---

Originally posted by [miloup](https://answers.ros.org/users/13906/miloup/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2